# Proposal for a "watch" tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, canonical, bookmarks

*I wasn't able to find something similar through search. If there is, let me know and I'll delete the question.*

As much as I like that we already have a favorites tab for starring questions, I feel as though it doesn't cover the different motivations for saving a question. For instance, a user may want to favorite a question because it has a canonical answer to a topic, and would love to have it as reference. However, there are other questions a user would like to star as well, perhaps because the user finds the question interesting, or believes that it is relevant to his or her own work, or because he or she simply would like to know the answer to the question. Thus, the user would like to "watch" this question so that it can be returned to later when answers have been provided.

As it currently stands, both types are saved under the "favorites" tab. While this is mostly fine, a user cannot simply purge a category of questions that are watched easily; for such questions, once the answer has been seen, usually it is no longer required to keep them. One would simply like to purge, for instance, the entire day's worth of "watched" questions.

I would love to hear what you think.

Comment: *"For instance, I may want to favorite a question because it has a canonical answer to a topic"* Use a bookmark.

Comment: @meagar I understand that's a solution. Concerning canonical answers, has the staff considered that perhaps having a canonical answer tab or section of the site is a possible part-solution to the endless duplication of questions/answers? This would allow access to canonicals that can be referenced much easier. If the community as a whole is aware of said canonical section, this would make the removal of duplicates rather trivial instead of being a burdensome task. With community-wide awareness, the task of duplication marking would not be as focused disproportionally around super users.

Comment: I think your solution is reasonable, but would the staff entertain my solution above? For consideration, not everyone keeps a tidy bookmark section, much less sync their bookmarks between browsers. Also, there will undoubtedly be times when they simply aren't available (e.g., using a public computer). By having it saved through the site, it's accessible as long as the user logs into the site. This makes SO entirely the platform instead of the combined browser with SO as platform.

Comment: Personally, I have no trouble using the existing systems in place. Upvote the question I like / will be interested in for time to come, find it back later through my user profile under the "votes" tab.